# Can't remove i2p browser

Tags: command-line, apt, dpkg, uninstall

When I open activities menu in ubuntu I see three same i2pbrowser icons and I can execute the application. However it does not exist in the list of installed package in Ubuntu Software.
I try to remove it using command line and here are the messages I get when I do that:

```
sudo apt remove i2p
```

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'i2p' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 186 not upgraded.
N: Ignoring file 'brave-browser-' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension

```
sudo apt-get purge i2p
```

Give the same previous message

```
sudo apt-get --force-yes remove i2p
```

Give the same previous message

```
sudo dpkg -r i2p
```

dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove i2p which isn't installed

Notice that when I run this command `apt list i2p` I get the following message:

Listing... Done
i2p/bionic,bionic 0.9.34-1ubuntu3 all
N: Ignoring file 'brave-browser-' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: I don't remember